# Keep referencing current time in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I would like to have my program reference the current time in Python.
But my program keeps printing and referencing a timestamp. I am using Python3.5.3.

```
import time

timenow = time.strftime("%X")

awake = "06:00:00" # turn on the lights at 6am
sleep = "22:00:00" # turn off the lights at 10pm

while True:
    print (timenow) # print the current time
    if awake <= timenow:
        print ("Lights On")
    elif timenow >= sleep:
        print ("Lights Off")

My current output is...

21:55:46
Lights On
21:55:46
Lights On
21:55:46
Lights On
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work as well.
If you are referencing time as date part that can be represented an int. I guess its better to compare numbers in this case rather then strings (as in your example).

```
import datetime


on = 6
off = 22


while True:
    ctime = datetime.datetime.now()
    status = 'Lights On' if on < ctime.hour < off else 'Lights Off'
    print('{}: {}'.format(ctime.strftime('%X'), status))
```

Comment: I would still like to reference the string "06:00:00" to the current time.

Comment: @mventers, Cool, just keep in mind even "06:00:00" < "22:00:00" is True, 
"6:00:00" < "22:00:00" is false

Comment: I have fixed this issue and run into this one as I think I know what you mean. I'll post another question.

Comment: I'm looking into this now. Could I use this to control down to the minute?

Comment: Pretty much sure, yes. But do you mean by hour and minute, or just minute. In first case it’s better represent start and end as time object. In second just use ctime.minute instead of ctime.hour

Comment: All good. I have worked it out. This is the base that I used and modified.

Answer (score 3):

I think you just need to move 1 line into the while loop:

```
import time

awake = "06:00:00" # turn on the lights at 6am
sleep = "22:00:00" # turn off the lights at 10pm

while True:
    timenow = time.strftime("%X") #moved this line into the while loop
    print (timenow) # print the current time
    if awake <= timenow:
        print ("Lights On")
    elif timenow >= sleep:
        print ("Lights Off")
```

The output should now look like:

```
Lights On
08:50:22
Lights On
08:50:23
Lights On
08:50:24
```

In the question, `timenow` gets set and is never updated.  So move that into the `while` loop flow so it gets created each time.  Just as good programing practice you may also want to toss a pause in there so it's just not hammering the CPU in the loop.  You could put this at the end of the while loop and it will wait 1 second before looping again:

```
....
elif timenow >= sleep:
    print ("Lights Off")
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. currentStatus = stillanoob

Comment: @mventers we all started somewhere :)  better to ask than be stuck for days!